# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied in spring boot for db other than h2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to configure oracle or mysql in spring boot, but while running the spring boot it is throwing **java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied**. But is working fine for h2 and for simple jdbc the same db credentials is working fine.

Below is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.spring-boot-thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>spring-boot-thymeleaf</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- H2 Database -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->                           
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>           
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>         
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0</version>            
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>                
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

and application.properties file

```
server.context-path=/api

#Basic Spring Boot Config for Oracle
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:O12CR102
spring.datasource.name=LEARNUSER
spring.datasource.password=LEARNUSER
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: If it works for H2 why should it work for oracle? If that user isn't known you have to create it.

Comment: @Deinum What I mean is if I replace the datasource with h2 details then it works and for simple jdbc connection the same oracle db url, username and password works but in spring boot its not working. I am using ojdbc7.jar

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `spring.datasource.username` I entered mistakenly `spring.datasource.name`

Used

```
spring.datasource.username=LEARNUSER
```

and remove

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```